# Error display in vaadin table

Tags: vaadin

I'm pretty new with vaadin framework, all working fine until... table header don't show properly,... I'm working on a portlet that runs on exoplatform, I'm using vaadin 6,  my table only display the first header, I tried everything but nothing seems to work.
Here is my code:

```
table = new Table("my table");
        table.setColumnHeaderMode(Table.COLUMN_HEADER_MODE_EXPLICIT);
        table.setPageLength(9);
        table.setWidth("100%");

        table.addContainerProperty("sad", String.class,  null);
        table.addContainerProperty("asd", Integer.class,  null);
        table.addContainerProperty("qwerty", Integer.class,  null);

        table.setColumnHeaderMode(Table.COLUMN_HEADER_MODE_EXPLICIT);
        table.setColumnHeader("sad", "sad");
        table.setColumnHeader("asd", "asd");
        table.setColumnHeader("qwerty", "qwerty");
```

Comment: remove table.setcolumnHeaderMode. pls check the doc http://vaadin.com/download/release/6.8/6.8.3/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#COLUMN_HEADER_MODE_EXPLICIT here

Comment: Use this as the last statement and try.`table.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] { "sad", "asd","qwerty" });`
I feel that some how table headers are not getting set. so use the above statement as the last property and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, try wrap your Table to Panel. It works for me.

It seems tables in VerticalLayout overlaps header of the next table, so just first header is shown. It is obvious when width of tables is different - then you see how one table overlaps header of the table below.

Hope that helps.